# how to create reusable KieBase in drools 7

Tags: java, drools

We are creating KIEBases pragmatically in below manner and storing compiled Kiebases in java map:

```
private static Map<String, KieBase> kieBaseMap = new HashMap<>();

public setKieBaseMap(String groupId,String drl){
    KieHelper kieHelper = new KieHelper();
    kieHelper.addContent(drl, ResourceType.DRL);
    Results results = kieHelper.verify(); 
    kieBaseMap.put(groupId,kieHelper.build()); 
}

StatelessKieSession buildKieSession(String ruleGroupId) {
    return kieBaseMap.get(ruleGroupId).newStatelessKieSession();
}
```

but if we are trying to execute same Kiebase again we are getting below Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakJoinNode.doLeftInserts(PhreakJoinNode.java:95)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakJoinNode.doNode(PhreakJoinNode.java:71)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.switchOnDoBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:552)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:538)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:373)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:333)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:169)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:127)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.reEvaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:212)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:87)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:1067)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1014)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1006)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1308)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1299)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1283)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.execute(StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:281)
```

I have set 
**`drools.getWorkingMemory().getKnowledgeBase().getConfiguration().setProperty(SequentialOption.PROPERTY_NAME,"true")`**

to execute all rules in sequence. Please help why I am getting this exception

Answer (score 0):

since I wanted to run Agenda groups in sequential manner , its needed to set SequentialAgendaOption.DYNAMIC at the time of module creation it self:

```
 kieSessionBuilder.setKieBaseMap(
        ruleGroupId, kieHelper.build(SequentialAgendaOption.DYNAMIC, SequentialOption.YES));
```

then this issue didnt come